# Using Java Pattern and Matcher to search and replace string before the XML declaration

Tags: xml, pattern-matching

I will need to parse an XML that contains a UID just before the XML declaration and therefore it is considered invalid. I have included an extra step where I use Java Pattern/Matcher in order to find the string (it is an ID that consists of 10 digit and a dollar sign) and replace it with *""*. I must also add that the file in question has .txt extension and the replacement will occur just before being renamed it (I have written a small utility for it) and being read to be parsed. Here is a snapshot of the XML:

```
UID$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RootElement
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="some-namespace">
    <ElementA attribute1a="1123" attribute2a= "3321.67">
        <ElementB="" attribute1b="2.46464" attribute2b="1.2345454"></ElementB>
    </ElementA>
</RootElement>
```

This is the Java class for the search/replace routine:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class FindReplace {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String originalFile = "D:\\invalid.txt";
            String outputFile = "D:\\_valid.txt";

            String search = "^[0-9]{10}\\$";
            String replace = "";

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalFile));
            File newFile = new File(outputFile);

            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
            String lineContents;
            while ((lineContents = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(search);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineContents);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    int count = 0;
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("found: " + count + " : " + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
                    String lineByLine = lineContents.replaceAll(search, replace);
                    writer.write(lineByLine);
                    System.out.println("This prints the content line by line: " + lineContents);
                }
            }
            writer.close();
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Although the substitution is successfully performed, I am only returned with the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

when the rest of the XML is discarded.

I am not sure why this is happening, can you help?

Thank you very much,

I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the line that contains "UID$" to be replaced with `""` and copy the rest of the content of the file into another file (valid.txt).

Currently where you loop through the file, you skip over the rest of the file; instead you can write it into the new file by refactoring like below:

```
while ((lineContents = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(search);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineContents);
            int count = 0;
            count++;
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("found: " + count + " : " + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
                String lineByLine = lineContents.replaceAll(search, replace);
                writer.write(lineByLine);
            } else {
                System.out.println("This prints the content line by line: " + lineContents);
                writer.write(lineContents + "\n");
            }
        }
```